# WallpaperManager.setBitmap() not setting wallpaper immediately

Tags: android, wallpaper

I set the wallpaper using this code:

```
void SetWallPaper(Context MyContext, Bitmap MyBitmap)
{   WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MyContext);
    wpm.setBitmap(MyBitmap);
}
```

It works well and the bitmap is set as a wallpaper always. BUT my problem is that many times the phone screen still shows last wallpaper until you refresh the screen. The ways of refreshing the screen can be:
1. Changing from one desktop to another using your finger. This makes the wallpaper to refresh.
2. Opening any application that creates an activity covering the whole home screen. When exiting it the home screen is refreshed and the last set bitmap is shown.

It sounds crazy, but the result is that the wallpaper has been changed but it is not displayed until the phone has to redraw it or something like that.
So, is there any way to force the phone to redraw or refresh it?

Answer (score 0):

To simply refresh an activity you can use:

```
finish();

startActivity(getIntent());
```

This refresh the current activity!

Comment: Sorry, it is not refreshing my activity. It is refreshing phone desktop to force to draw the wallpaper

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983584/android-refresh-bitmap-with-new-data

Comment: I think that is not my situation